# can not find current location via gps or network

Tags: android, networking, gps, location

i need to find current location, either with network or gps.
i searched over internet and in stackoverflow but i cann't find what's wrong with this code.
i also set this parameter in manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"
```

so here is my code:

```
LocationManager locationManager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    findCurrentLocation();
    //some other stuff here
}

public void findCurrentLocation()
{           
    boolean networkEnabled = false;
    boolean gpsEnabled = false;

    currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

    if(currentLocation == null)
    {
        currentLocation = new Location("sometext");

        locationFindDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Find Your Location", "Please Wait", false);

        try
        {
            networkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        try
        {
            gpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

        if((networkEnabled == false) && (gpsEnabled == false))
        {
            locationFindDialog.dismiss();
            showMessage("we need gps or sim card(or network) to find your location");
            //show message
            //you need at least one provider
            return;
        }

        if(networkEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, networkLocationListener);                
        }

        if(gpsEnabled)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsLocationListener);
        }
    }

    private final LocationListener networkLocationListener = new LocationListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {

        currentLocation.set(location);          

        //unregister listener
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(gpsLocationListener);         
        locationFindDialog.dismiss();           
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }       
};

private final LocationListener gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        currentLocation.set(location);          

        //unregister listener
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(networkLocationListener);         
        locationFindDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {

    }

};

private Location getLastKnownLocation()
{
    Location location = null;
    List<String> providers = locationManager.getAllProviders();

    for(String provider : providers)
    {
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if(location != null) 
        {               
            return location;
        }
    }       
    return null;
}
```

no mater how much i wait, the app don't give me the location.
what's wrong with this code and how i can fix it?

Comment: did u use the internet user permission?

Comment: @Araibkarim: no, is it necessary?

Comment: By looking here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener) I can see that you're not giving enough time for the provides (either GPS or NETWORK) to refresh the location. Try `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2*1000*60, 0, networkLocationListener);//2 mins` and set this time for GPS to be 5 minutes minimum.

Comment: @g00dy: thanks alot, now it can find location via GPS, but it can't find location via network(simcard), how i can solve this?

Comment: Your `if` statements (`if(networkEnabled)` and `if(gpsEnabled)`) are one after another, put them in `if(){} else{}`, so that you get only one of them.

Comment: i'm aware of that. i want to register listener for both of them so (if both of them are enabled), so they both searching for location, and the one report faster i use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a solution for this problem, the idea is finding cellId and lac manually, then send them to google secret API, and find latitude and longitude of cell tower, it's not too accurate (because it's cell tower location not user location), but enough for me.

refer to this address for more info:
http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/01/convert-celllocation-to-real-location.html